# Query (or LINQ in Entity Framework) for getting user's rank

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have a SQL Server database with a table named `Users`.

This table has 2 columns: `XP` (int32) and `Name` (nvarchar).

I need a SQL query or Linq (this is better because I'm using Entity Framework in C#) that gets the `Name` and ranks everyone based on `XP` and display the rank of this name + the rank of the previous 1 people + the rank of the next 1 people.

Something like this :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In EF terms it seems like it could just be:

```
var d = db.Users
  .OrderByDescending(u => u.Xp)
  .AsEnumerable()
  .Select((u, i) => new { Rank=i+1, User = u })
  .ToDictionary(at => at.Rank);
```

You list all your users out of the DB in order of XP, and you use the overload of `Select((user,index)=>...)` to assign the rank (the index + 1) and for convenience let's put them in a dictionary indexed by rank

Now you have a dictionary you can keep and repeatedly look up in where, for any given user, you can get the surrounding users by the rank of the user you already know:

```
var user = d.Values.FirstOrDefault(u => u.User.Name == "user6");
var prev = d[user.Rank - 1];
var next = d[user.Rank + 1];
```

You need some code to prevent a KeyNotFoundException if you find the top or bottom ranked user because if you find the user with Rank 1 by name, you cannot retrieve the user with Rank 0 (they don't exist). You didn't say what to do in this situation in your original post, you can use ContainsKey to test if the dictionary contains a particular rank, or you can use GetValueOrDefault, or TryGetValue to attempt to get a user - these methods don't crash if the user isn't found but you will need to decide what to do if they aren't

Comment: @Jonas ToDictionary won't throw a KeyNotFound. The only place that will throw is if the user with eg Rank=1 is found and the code that attempts to retrieve rank=0 is run. I specifically caution about this on the last line of the post, and advise use of TryGetValue. The OP did not state what to do in the case of attempting to retrieve a user who has no ranked user above or below them. Some things have to be left to the OP to implement; we cannot write their entire program for them

Comment: @Charlieface to trigger a download of all users, because though theoretically it could translate to eg ROW_NUMBER()OVER(), EF isn't capable of translating the `Select((e,i)...)` overload that calculates the ranking

Comment: @Charlieface They want strenuously to build something like `RANK` or `ROW_NUMBER` in C# with Linq. That's just horrible because it's unnecessary complicated, not performant, not what Linq is designed for. Such functionality is far better be done in pure SQL where `RANK` and `ROW_NUMBER` are build-in functions that run quite fast and are very easy to use. Yes, OP asked also for a Linq solution, but the honest answer here would be: Please don't do that, use pure SQL. The issue you must handle possible `KeyNotFoundException` shows that, too.

Comment: @JonasMetzler what line raises the KeyNotFound exception?

Comment: @flackoverstow After the last changes on your code (which you have done after my comment), the code works. Thank you for improving it.

Comment: Welcome.. I still can't find anything that would throw KNF other than perhaps pulling user3, as the attempt to get a higher user would fail but thanks for the nudge to check it

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Try this

```
SELECT
    XP,
    name,
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY XP DESC) AS Ranking
FROM UserExperience;
```

Comment: Thank u , Please help me Add the `where` in it ... for example `where name = 'user2'`
just show one record

Comment: bro can u say me how i should to do ?
`WHERE Ranking BETWEEN 3 AND 7` now work ... infact sql server cant see "Ranking"

Comment: You need to wrap it in subquery

Comment: @siggemannen I have tested many modes, I think that using this method "rank" is wrong .

Comment: @siggemannen I can't even get the rank of this "user" + her next people

Comment: @YasimYasin I guess something like this is intended? `WITH ranked
AS
(SELECT
  xp,
  name,
  RANK() OVER (ORDER BY XP DESC) AS ranking
FROM users),
ranking_compare AS
(SELECT ranking FROM ranked WHERE name = 'User6')
SELECT r.ranking, r.name
FROM ranked r 
INNER JOIN ranking_compare rc
ON r.ranking between rc.ranking - 1 and rc.ranking + 1
ORDER BY r.ranking`, isn't it?

Comment: @JonasMetzler I got my answer, but thank you too
I think this code is heavy for me... 
because I don't have the power to analyze queries in MS Sql Server
And I prefer to use LINQ now,
You mean it is better to use "procedure Sql server" here?

Comment: @YasimYasin Yes, in my opinion, it is far better to do not use Linq here, see my comment for Charlieface below the answer you accepted.